# How to find a coordinate trasnformation for Lienard system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand the Lienard equation:

[image]

In particular how I get from the system

[image]

to the system

[image]
[image]

By looking at (1) it kind of makes sense to me to define $y=x'+F(x)$, so that we end up with two new differential equations.

**Question:**
What transformation $T$ from the following theorem would transform the first system into the second? For some reason I can't find it.

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Just set $y=v-F(x)$ or in the other direction $v=y+F(x)$. // It is better to use different letters for different objects, so rename $y$ to $v$ in the second system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Do you mean $T(x,y)=(x,y+F(x)$, $T^{-1}(u,v))=(u,v-F(u))$? If I look at $f(T(x,y))$ or $\tilde{f}(T^{-1}(u,v))$ I only get one entry right I think. I guess I am missing something.

Comment: @user577215664 It is from some notes I found in the internet.

Comment: Yes on the transformations. But what is $f(T(x,y))$? $f$ only depends on the first component, and that is always $x$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann My bad, with $f$ I meant the right hand side of the first system.

Comment: Then you want $\Phi_1(T^{-1}(u,v))$ which should expand to the right sides $\Phi_2(u,v)$ of the second system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, but somehow I am not able to do that. I get $\Phi_{1}(u,v-F(u))=(v-F(u),-g(u)-f(u)(v-F(u)))$. The first slot looks good, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: You have, of course, to balance this to the left side $y'=v'-F'(u)u'=v'-f(u)(v-F(u))$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139022/discussion-between-hans-and-lutz-lehmann).